# How to create a SQL using 'between' in Elixir Ecto

Tags: between, elixir, ecto

I want to create a SQL using the keywork 'between' in Elixir Ecto.

I know how to create a sql using `like`

`where: like(t.descript, ^some_description)`

But when I try to do it in the same way as `like`

`where: between(t.start_date, ^start_date, ^end_date),`

I got the "not valid" error msg

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `between(t.start_date(), ^start_date, ^end_date)` is not a valid query expression.**
```

How can I do it the right way?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think Ecto provides a `between` clause. You could achieve your task by using

```
where: t.start_date >= ^start_date,
where: t.start_date <= ^end_date
```

Comment: Do you mean `start_date <= ^end_date`?

Comment: Just for others, you can combine these into one line with an `and`.  `where: t.start_date >= ^start_date and t.start_date <= ^end_date`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `fragment` to do this.

```
where: fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", t.date, ^start_date, ^end_date)
```

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.1.4/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1

Answer (score 2):

You can also make your own `between` macro using the fragment answer @Horvo gave:

```
@doc """
Checks if the first value is between the second and third value.
"""
defmacro between(value, left, right) do
  quote do
    fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", unquote(value), unquote(left), unquote(right))
  end
end
```

and use it like you wish you could:

```
where: between(t.start_date, ^start_date, ^end_date)
```